# Use the Facebook Android SDK ShareDialog to check in at a location

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, checkin, fbsdksharedialog

Incentivized sharing is not allowed in the Facebook SDK, but incentivized check in is allowed.

However, the check in ability has been deprecated in the SDK docs, and they say it was added to the share dialog, but there's no documentation on how to do this.

I've searched all over SO and the internet to no avail. My sharedialog works fine, but it just wont check in at the place.

What is the approved way to use the Android Facebook SDK to check in at a location?

Here's my current ShareDialog code...

```
 Bitmap image = bitmap;
                    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                            .setBitmap(image)
                            .build();
                    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                            .addPhoto(photo)
                            .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                                    .setHashtag(hashtag)
                                    .build())
                            .build();

                    ShareDialog.show(ShareActivity.this, content);
```